# Is the a ExecuteMso equivalent in Office.js?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am trying to use a native button command programmatically in Office.js. More specifically, I am trying to use the pre-existing copy button command since Office.js only provides the CopyFrom function for any copy-paste uses.

I couldn't find any documentation for this online so I was wondering if there was any way to use something like the ExecuteMso method or if there are any plans for this to be added in future updates?

Comment: There is no equivalent for web add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that there is no way to do that in Office.js. But you can submit the idea to the [Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/user/ssoregistrationpage?dest_url=https:%2F%2Ftechcommunity.microsoft.com%2Ft5%2Fforums%2Fpostpage%2Fboard-id%2FMicrosoft365DeveloperPlatform).